# Can webpack alias a single file depending on environment variable

Tags: javascript, webpack

Given this folder structure

```
/products
-foo
 -foo.js
-bar
 -bar.js
```

I'd like to be able to `import` or `require` either `foo.js` or `bar.js` depending on an environment variable called `BUILD_PRODUCT`.
I want to import as `import Product from "product"`

Webpack should resolve the `product[.js]` with the help of the `BUILD_PRODUCT` to `/products/$BUILD_PRODUCT/$BUILD_PRODUCT.js`

So if `export BUILD_PRODUCT=foo` it should resolve

`import Product from "product"` to `import Product from "/products/foo/foo.js"`

Is that possible?

I have already defined the `modulesDirectories` as:

```
const PRODUCT_DIR = path.join(__dirname, "products", process.env.BUILD_PRODUCT)
const PRODUCT_SRC_DIR = path.join(PRODUCT_DIR, "src")

modulesDirectories: [
  PRODUCT_DIR,
  PRODUCT_SRC_DIR,
  SRC_DIR,
  "node_modules",
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. This answer its from this [repo](https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack).

You can check the environment with this sentences:

```
var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isTest = ENV === 'test' || ENV === 'test-watch';
var isProd = ENV === 'build';
```

It takes the ENV from the npm scripts, ill explain this. If i run this script:

```
"build"
```

isProd will be true, and if you run the followings command:

```
"test"
```

isTest will be true and finally if your are developing, you inly need to run this command

```
"server"
```

so isTest and isProd will false both.

This is one way to the the environment. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks but this does not answer my question.